# "This's" instead of "this is"

Tags: contractions, apostrophe

Is it popular to contract "**this is**" to "**this's**"? Or is it better to keep the full form?

- This's where we'll go tomorrow.

Or

- This is where we'll go tomorrow.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38212/why-do-we-say-this-is-instead-of-thiss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we use < 's > for *has* or *is*, this represents a contraction in the pronunciation. Instead of saying *has* or *is* as a separate word with its own vowel, we reduce the word to just /s/. This /s/ gets attached to the previous word. The result is that we lose a syllable in the pronunciation:

- Ben is here.
- Ben's here.

In the first sentence *Ben is* represents two syllables. But in the second sentence *Ben's* represents just one syllable.

However, we cannot always reduce the auxiliaries *has* or *is* to just /s/. The reason is that English has a rule that we cannot put a suffix /s/ after another s-like sound. S-like sounds  are called *sibilants*.

The English sibilants are /s, z, ʃ, ʒ/. The first three are the sounds at the ends of the words *yes, jazz, fish*. The last one, /ʒ/, is the middle consonant in the word *vision*. It occurs at the ends of some unusual words like *rouge, mirage* and *beige*, which we borrowed from French.

The special compound sounds (affricates) /tʃ, dʒ/ also finish as a sibilant sound. These affricates are found at the end of the words *watch* and *judge*.

When we have a word like *has* or *is* after a sibilant sound, we cannot reduce the word to just /s/. We must keep the vowel in the word:

- Chris is here. /krɪs ɪz hɪə(r)/
- This is blue. /ðɪs ɪz blu:/
- */krɪss hɪə(r)/ (ungrammatical)
- */ðɪss blu:/ (ungrammatical)

For this reason you will not see  *has* or *is* represented as < 's > after sibilant sounds in normal writing in published books or on notices. However, in very informal writing, such as in text messages, people may often misrepresent *is* or *has* as , < 's > even after sibilant sounds. This is just to save time when writing. It does not represent a contraction in the speech.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

**This's** does not exist (certainly not in British English or any English dialect I am aware of). Always use **this is**.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/this%27s

Answer (score 0):

This is an exception word as far as I know and I've never heard of this's although I do know it applies to other words in speech such as running is so tiring>running's so tiring and to names in writing and speech such as Ben is here> Ben's here. (Canadian Native English Speaker btw).

Comment: Hello!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and review our [help] to understand how best to use this site.  We do appreciate regional insight, but that insight should include an explanation of why your explanation is useful to the OP.  Raw observations are not always useful.  For example, in the mountain west region of the U.S., "this's" is a very common contraction.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the accepted answer.  I think that **'s** meaning "is" or "has" isn't always pronounced /s/ and can sometimes be added to words or names that already end with /s/.

Cambridge specifies the pronunciation of the contraction **'s** [as follows](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/s?q=%27s), in my view correctly:  / -s/ /-z/ /-ɪz/

I think we can say and write things like "Max's here" (which does not necessarily sound the same as "Max is here", because for some speakers a schwa may replace the /ɪ/) and "Max's been gone a long time".  It is colloquial usage, but whether it is any more informal than "Tim's here" is debatable.

However, it is very rare to see "This's".  But if I did see it I would assume it represented a rapid or casual pronunciation, perhaps with a schwa replacing the "i" of "is".

Comment: A couple of points. For speakers who allow /ə/ instead of /ɪ/ for unstressed *is*, these are both pronunciations for the *is* when spelled out as normal. Secondly, I agree that '*Max's here*' is ever so slightly less bad than other transgressions orthography-wise. But this is only because proper names denoting humans frequently occur with the genitive suffix < 's >, as in *Max's dog*. This rarely occurs with inanimate objects: # *The box's corners*. The former is not permitted in the standard orthography. The cliticisation represented by < 's > for *is* or *has* involves the loss of a vowel.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Where can I find the evidence that most people would consider "Max's here" to be a transgression?